# UITextView stop writing outside bounds

Tags: ios

I have a UItextView with disabled scrolling. Is it possible to stop the user from writing more content in the UItextView so that the writing will remain on screen and not disappear in the hidden side of the text view?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` to calculate the size of the text after the edit and decide whether to allow the edit to complete.